# Came across an interesting error when working with pointers and rand() C++

Tags: c++

I'm starting to work on a small project to test my knowledge and I came across something odd and wouldn't mind having whatever is happening explained to me.

First off my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void mazeLayout(int* p_height, int* p_width, int* p_seed, string* p_curPath){
int start;
int stop;
int temp = *p_seed;
cout << temp << "\n";

while(temp > *p_width || temp > *p_height || temp <= 0){
    if(temp <= 0){
        temp = temp+8;
    }
    temp = temp-7;
    cout << temp << "\n";
}



};

int main()
{
    int width;
    int *p_width = &width;
    int height;
    int *p_height = &height;
    int seed;
    int *p_seed = &seed;
    string curPath;
    string *p_curPath = &curPath;
    int **maze;
    srand(time(NULL));
    seed = rand()+8*24;
    seed = seed%50;

    cout << "Welcome to the maze generator\n\n";
    cout << "Width: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Height: ";
    cin >> height;

    maze = new int* [height];
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        maze[i] = new int[width];
    }

    mazeLayout(p_height, p_width, p_seed, p_curPath);


    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++ ){
        delete[] maze[i];
    }
    delete[] maze;
}
```

It may be sloppy and as I had pointed out to me in a previous post I should probably be working with `vector` rather than pointers if I'm just a beginner, I'm not looking for critiques on that currently(they are welcome though).

Anyway, back to my point. When I run this and plug in a value for `width` that is > 10 and a value for `height` that is between 5 & 8 I get an odd output.

Multiple times it prints out something like:

```
once 007417B8 is 6584960
```

and then the program ends giving me the signal that everything ran fine with no errors.

Any other combinations of numbers results in a normal outcome(outside of a combination such as 14 & 3 which results in a crash due to a bad memory address)

Can someone tell me what exactly is happening here?

Comment: What is the reason for declaring all of those pointers at the beginning of `main`?  They don't serve any real purpose, except to get you into trouble that need not happen.  It seems you're falling victim to "if the function requires a pointer, then I must declare a pointer."  Wrong:   `mazeLayout(&height,&width, &seed, &curPath);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I guess that would be more effective, I'm honestly not even sure why I decided that'd be more effective than using a ref.

Comment: The `&` in my comment is the *address-of* operator, not a reference.  Yes, they share the same syntax, but one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now. The book I'm using didn't cover the fact that that was even a possibility! Thank you so much for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @FutureWizard In such case, you might want to pick up a [better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you require

```
maze = new int* [height];
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
//                   ^
//                   ^            
    maze[i] = new int[width];
}
```

as currently, you are using the value of `width` to loop over. If `height` is bigger than `width`, then this will result in unallocated arrays for some of the `maze[i]` in your code as it stands. Then attempts to access this unallocated memory later in code will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: You and Agnew hit the nail right on the head, that error is gone! Any clue as to why it decided to print out all of those `once 007417B8 is 6584960`?

Comment: @FutureWizard Not really. When you hit undefined behaviour anything can happen....

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in the `for` loop:

```
maze = new int* [height];
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    maze[i] = new int[width];
}
```

`maze` points to an array of `height` elements, but then your `for` loop goes up to `width`. If `width` is larger than `height`, you get Undefined Behaviour (probably writing into random memory), under which anything can happen.